# Add retrievable metadata to multiple field in sunspot solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sunspot-solr

I'll use a practical example taken from the sunspot solr docs. Let's say we have posts with comments, then a post indexes its title and the comments:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title
    text :comments do
      comments.map { |comment| comment.body }
    end
  end
end
```

What I want to know is the comment that matched when we search the posts (if it matched using the comments field), so I can show the user the posts AND the comment that matched the search. If there is more than one match, get the best match based on the score. I was thinking of adding the id as metadata to the comments field, but I couldn't find a way to do this.

Is there any way to attach some kind of non-indexed metadata (in this case the id of each comment) that can be retrieved when there is a match using that field? Any other suggestion to solve this?

Comment: You question is not really about your sunspot, but about your schema. Plz, edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should store  posts and comments on different documents. You can put the post id at the comment document, so you may know which post owns each comment.

My fields suggestions is:

```
id - if you have the risk of getting the same id for a comment and a post, you should use some kind of prefix at the document id. In this case, you have another field to store the original id
_type (post or comment) - 
post_id - this field will store the post id, a comment is child. It will be empty at the post documents
title (empty for comments, maybe?)
content - the actual text a comment or post has
text - the field that contains all text you want to query in a document, via copyfield (only if you don't want to boost the individual fields)
<any other fields you may need>
```

You may query your for posts or comments simply doing ?q=text:"foo" and you will retrieve all documents that match foo. You can then query for the post_id's returned, or maybe you may try some kind of join. Take a look at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join. You would do something like **?q=({join from=post_id to=id}text:"foo") (+text:foo +_type:post)**